# How to replicate iPhone's wifi network selection popup view

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog

As far as I know, there's no standard UI component that looks like Apple's wifi selection popup:

[image]

Are there any open source custom components out there that I can use to get a similar popup in my app?  If not, how would I go about writing my own?

I did find this on Google Images:

[image]

So I guess it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add subviews to a UIAlertView and make a custom behavior. I would recommend looking at this link:

http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2009/07/15/look-uialertview-is-dating-uitableview.html

I also found this similar question:

[How to add UITableView to UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395389/how-to-add-uitableview-to-uialertview)

Answer (score 0):

Its a UIAlertView with a UITableView inside it.

The top view containing the switch is a UITableViewCell - Grouped with a UISwitch ontop.

The bottom view is just a UITableView.